# How to PXE boot systems that only have EFI/UEFI firmware (with no BIOS downgrade option)?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, pxe-boot, uefi

I run/work in a heterogeneous environment.  The network is mostly run on Windows servers for DNS and DHCP.  We use Linux for various other things.

I have some brand new Toshiba Laptops that that will not boot off of PXE boot server, that hosts our OS install media.

Our DHCP and DNS is running on a Windows 2012r2 Server.

Our PXE tftp boot server is running on Ubuntu.

How can I get my Toshiba Laptop to boot?

Comment: probably you should add what are you trying to boot/install on those Toshiba; your question is incomplete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot use the same PXE boot image (generally named `pxelinux.0`) as with the old BIOS systems.  You need a new version, generally named `bootx64.efi`.

http://www.syslinux.org/archives/2014-January/021404.html

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-netboot-pxe-config-efi.html

Comment: You are mixing things up; you first talk about pxelinux.0 (BIOS) and after that you mention `bootx64.efi` which is a `generic` name for an UEFI bootloader. Then what are you going to boot?? syslinux.efi renamed as bootx64??? and after that what? are you going to chainload? to what? if you want to boot anything other than a Linux kernel you are in trouble but surely you already know all of that right?

Comment: Maybe I am a bit naive.  I can boot a Microsoft WinPE image (iso) from pxelinux.0 along with a number of other operating systems, Linux/Ubuntu, Linux/CentOS, VMware, DOS, NetBSD, and OpenBSD.  I can successfully boot ipxe+wimboot to WinPE.  I will update my question and answer accordingly.